# Почему при запуске Activity первым обрабатывается элемент Spinner'а и как это устранить?

Tags: java, android

Приветствую, я пишу математическое приложение, на конкретном `Activity` мне нужно определить действие (`RadioGroup`) и переменные для него (`Spinner`) после чего действие выполнится.

В принципе, программа производит верные и точные вычисления, однако выполняется она несколько не верно, с конца.. Т.к. при запуске `Activity` первым обрабатывается `Spinner` (не зависимо от того нажал ты его, или нет, он просто при запуске обрабатывает первый элемент списка, т.е `znachn1` = 9), а потом уже `RadioGroup`..

При этом если попытаться выбрать сначала какой-то конкретный `RadioButton` (т.е., сначала про инициализировать действие для переменной `znachn1`, а потом выбрать её значение из списка(не относится к 3-ему `RadioButton`)), тогда то самое заранее обработанное значение 9 блокируется, и не даёт выбрать другие значения, из-за чего при переходе на другой `Activity Toast` выводит вычисления произведённые только со значением 9.

Если же сначала выбрать значение, а потом действие, то всё считает как надо, но в таком случая нарушается алгоритм, который мне по факту и нужен..

Я попытался программно отключать `Spinner`, при запуске, и включать при нажатии `RadioButton'а`, но это не помогло..

Можете подсказать как решать данную проблему?

**Код Activity:**

```
public class MessageActivity1 extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView celzadach, poyas4, poyas5, poyas6;
    RadioGroup rgroup;
    RadioButton sravnenkr1, sravnenkr2, sravnenkr3;
    Spinner spn2;
    String prioritet[] = {"9", "8", "7", "6", "5", "4", "3", "2", "1"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2;
    double znachn1;
    Button sootnesen1;
    static double d, b;
    boolean block;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_message1);

        celzadach = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.celzadach);
        Intent intent5 = getIntent();
        String message1 = intent5.getStringExtra("message1");
        celzadach.setText(message1);

        poyas4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.poyas4);
        poyas4.setText("Определение важности критериев сравнения относительно заявленной цели:");

        poyas5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.poyas5);
        poyas5.setText("Какой из сравниваемых критериев более предпочтительный?");

        poyas6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.poyas6);
        poyas6.setText("Предпочтительней на сколько?");

        sravnenkr1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.sravnenkr1);
        Intent intent6 = getIntent();
        String message2 = intent6.getStringExtra("message2");
        sravnenkr1.setText(message2);

        sravnenkr2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.sravnenkr2);
        Intent intent7 = getIntent();
        String message3 = intent7.getStringExtra("message3");
        sravnenkr2.setText(message3);

        sravnenkr3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.sravnenkr3);
        sravnenkr3.setText("Сравниваемые критерии одинаково важны");

        spn2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnPrioritet);
        adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, prioritet);
        spn2.setAdapter(adapter2);
        block = false;
        spn2.setEnabled(block);
        spn2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position2, long id) {
                switch (position2) {
                    case 0:
                        znachn1 = 9;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        znachn1 = 8;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        znachn1 = 7;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        znachn1 = 6;
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        znachn1 = 5;
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        znachn1 = 4;
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        znachn1 = 3;
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        znachn1 = 2;
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        znachn1 = 1;
                        break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
            }
        });

        rgroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.RadioGroup1);
        rgroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, @IdRes int q) {
                switch (q) {
                    case R.id.sravnenkr1:
                        d = znachn1;
                        b = 1 / znachn1;
                        block = true;
                        spn2.setEnabled(block);
                        break;
                    case R.id.sravnenkr2:
                        b = znachn1;
                        d = 1 / znachn1;
                        block = true;
                        spn2.setEnabled(block);
                        break;
                    case R.id.sravnenkr3:
                        d = 1;
                        b = 1;
                        break;
                }
            }
        });

        sootnesen1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sootnesen1);
        sootnesen1.setText("Далее");
        sootnesen1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent8 = new Intent(MessageActivity1.this, MessageActivity2.class);
                Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"w0="+w0, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast1.show();
                startActivity(intent8);
            }

        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Добавьте первым элементом в `Spinner` что-то типа "Выберите значение...".

Comment: Если сделать так, то при вычислении выводится 0.0